# Loop the program until 0(exit)(java)

Tags: java, loops, exit, restriction

I have this java code that basically just prints a christmas tree of X height.However, the program ask for the number, then print the tree and then just end.I would like it to loop until I enter 0,wich would end the program,and also I would like to make it print only if the number entered is from 1-40(not over 40).Im begining in the java world and I dont know how to do that.Heres my code for now:

```
public class xtree {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("please enter a number: ");
        int temp = scan.nextInt();
        int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
        int y = x/2;  
        int z = 1;  
        for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
            {
                out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
            {
                out.print("*");
            }
            out.println(); 
            y--;
            z+=2; 
        }
        for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) 
        {
            out.print(" ");
        }
        out.println("*"); 
    }
}
```

Thank you, im a beginner to java so please be lenient ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would separate the method out into two:

- A `printChristmasTree` method, which accepts the height as a parameter
- Your `main` method, which just deals with taking user input and calling `printChristmasTree` or exiting

Most of your current `main` method would go into the `printChristmasTree`, and `main` would be a loop. Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number (0-40): ");
        int height = scan.nextInt();
        if (height == 0) {
            // Exit the program
            return;
        } else if (height >= 1 && height <= 40) {
            printChristmasTree(height);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

There are other approaches you could use instead of returning from a `while (true)` loop, but this looks the simplest to me.

The separation of the "taking input" from the "printing the Christmas tree" aspects leads to much more readable code than keeping them combined, in my view - and it's more flexible in terms of things like writing a different program to print *all* valid Christmas trees.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("please enter a number: ");

    int temp = scan.nextInt();
    while (temp>0) {
        int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
        int y = x/2;  
        int z = 1;  
        for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println(); 
            y--;
            z+=2; 
        }
        for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
        temp = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for doing that:

```
public class xtree {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int temp;
        do{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
            out.print("please enter a number: ");
            temp = scan.nextInt();

            if(temp >= 1 && temp <= 40){ //don't display a tree higher than 40
                int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
                int y = x/2;  
                int z = 1;  
                for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
                    {
                        out.print(" ");
                    }
                    for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
                    {
                        out.print("*");
                    }
                    out.println(); 
                    y--;
                    z+=2; 
                }
                for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) 
                {
                    out.print(" ");
                }
                out.println("*"); 
            }else if(temp != 0){
                out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 40!");
            }
        }while(temp != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, this works, however went I enter 0 this still return error message Please enter a number between 1 and 40! before exiting; how could I make it exit without entering the error message? thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer, just changed 

... } else { ...

to 

}else if(temp != 0){

This should work now ;)